# How to find evidence of outbound network traffic in linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, tomcat, bitnami

I have setup a standard web application server in AWS using a bitnami Apache-Tomcat AMI.  The instance is running in a public subnet with all Outbound traffic open but only allowing traffic inbound through port 22 (only from my IP) and ports 80 & 443 from the Load Balancer.

I have been recently hit with a massive data charge because somehow the instance has transferred (outbound) in excess of 14TB over the last couple of weeks.  I shut the server down 2 days ago and just fired it up and am looking around for any logs of any description that might show me what was happening. (The basic AWS reporting is useless).  I have only just installed IPTraf so I can at least monitor network traffic (all is quiet) and have also setup some Cloud Watch alarms to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Any ideas where I might be able to look for evidence of what was causing the massive transfer of data outbound and where to?

Cheers

Comment: Do you need to allow the instance to initiate outbound connections at all?!

Comment: I can definitely review that and in most cases probably no. I had it turned on so I could at least install stuff, talk to the internet etc.. It does need to speak to a MySQL RDS instance however I can specifically just allow that.  I am just hoping there is someway I can find out what happened in the first instance...

Comment: FYI, AWS is likely to forgive the charges. Contact support.

Comment: Yeah, already have and they are likely to based on my conversations with them. However they want to know if I have corrected the issue, and short of terminating the instance I would like to try and find out what happened and mitigate it.

Comment: You can find evidence of traffic:
- in iptables stats (if iptables used)
- or using tcpdump or tshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the high spike in outbound data happened again early this morning. I used tshark (Thanks @tonioc) to see that data was being sent to multiple IP's around the world and more specifically China.. :-/ Anyway i was creating some dumps from tshark and storing them in the /tmp folder and realised that there was a file called fake.cfg sitting there. I straight away thought this as suspicious so did some research and found that my server had been hacked using vulnerabilities in the host-manager which comes with the tomcat-apache bitnami instance I was running. Most likely the password was guess and they installed a malicious app.  There was also a "hosts-manager" app in my webapps folder which shouldn't have been there and within contained an index.jsp file that had a whole range of malicious scripts.

Anyway I have cleared out all of those scripts and completely removed access to host-manager and any other bitnami pages from my webapps folder and now only my webapp can be access. I have also ensured all default passwords have been changed and monitoring on my instances for spikes in outbound data have been put in place.

Some articles on the issues:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/628222/Tomcat/fake-cfg-tmp-directory-lot
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017515/aws-network-traffic-high-due-to-folder-29881-and-fake-cfg
http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2013/08/09/old-tomcat-5-5-installs-being-exploited/

I think I am all good for now.

Cheers